# Where does this function gets its values?

Tags: javascript, function, inline-functions

This is an example from a book. The function returns TRUE if even and FALSE if not. I don't understand how it works. This is what I understand:

1. 42 binds to n
2. Creating "even" function
3. x binds to n which = 42
4. x != 0
5. initiating "else"
6. creating "odd" function
7. odd(42 - 1)
8. Initiating "!even(41)".

**What does JS do with "even(41)"? where TRUE comes from? The way I understand it should return TRUE only when x === 0**

```js
document.write(
  ((n) => {
    const even = (x) => {
      if (x === 0) return true;
      else {
        const odd = (y) => !even(y);
        return odd(x - 1);
      }
    }
    return even(n)
  })(42)
)
```

Comment: It's a recursive function, `x === 0` is the base case.

Comment: @elclanrs were TRUE comes from for 42? cant understand

Comment: Try to follow it for 1 first, then 2 and then reason about 42.

Comment: Yes, try writing down the recursion manually, like they did here for factorial for example https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node15.html

Comment: This seems to be a terrible way of finding if a number is even or odd

Comment: I'd like to find the publisher of this book and give him a long lesson about how to make an actually *useful* example of recursion...

Comment: @redu It is definitely that.  I think it's intended as a lesson in recursion and it's just a really bad lesson.

Comment: It creates two functions `even` and `odd` and it is based on the idea that if `A` is even then `A-1` is odd (eg. parity changes for consecutive numbers). Also, don't write code like this. It's a bad idea to create functions inside other functions

Comment: And the most terrible, ugly and disgusting part of this piece of "code" is `(n-1)` times redefining the `odd` function.

Comment: Possibly better to understand (less syntax magic): `const odd = (y) => { return !even(y); }`

Answer (score 3):

It's intentionally confusing. Follow the logic.

If n is not 0, we create a new function called odd which calls even and reverses the boolean value of even.

We then *call that function* with n-1.

So essentially, it's like a while loop where you keep subtracting 1 from the number and reversing its truthiness or falsiness on each step deeper, until you have a 0.  If the function is called an even number of times, it's even.  If it's called an odd number of times, it's odd.

Comment: In addition to being intentionally confusing, it's also a remarkably inefficient way to check for even or odd. I assume it's meant to demonstrate recursion, but it's not even very good at that...

Comment: Agreed, just made the same comment to the OP.

Comment: I think the confusing part is that `odd` is declared inside the scope of the `else` block *inside* the `even` function - it would be much clearer if they were on the same level. Whether that really was intentional stands to question.

Comment: @Paul but how does it know how many times the function is called? for example we have (2). odd(2 - 1) is not zero, and it doesn't return TRUE. Were TRUE comes from?

Comment: Because each time it's called the return value is reversed from the next one.  It doesn't really need to know how many times.  if it's called once, it's returned as !true, so false.  If twice, it's !!true, so true.  three times, !!!true, so false again, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The following code performs the same logic as the book example, including use of recursion, but prevents an infinite loop if `isEven` is called with a non integral or negative value.

```
const isEven = (n) =>
{
    const even = (x) =>  x ? !even(x-1) : true;

    return even( Math.abs(Math.floor(n)));
}
isEven( 42)
```

Now the bench logic test is fairly straight forward:

```
even( 0) returns true;
even( 1) returns !even( 1-1), which is !even(0), which is false;
even( 2) returns !even( 2-1), which is !even(1), which is true;
```

and so on for higher numbers. Each increment of the parameter value executes an additional, recursive call to even, which complements the "even-ness" of the number below it, until reaching zero which is hard coded as being even.

The end result is that if `even` is called an odd number of times (for an even number) `isEven` returns `true`; and if `even` is called an an even number of times (for an odd number) `isEven` returns false.